# C: Beginner question about bidimensional array in struct

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct

I would like to create a struct that contains a bidimensional array in C, but I don't know how to initialize it because I don't know the dimensions. Is there a way to do it?

```
struct myStruct {
      int m[][];
};
```

Comment: You'll have to use pointers `int **m` and use `malloc` to allocate memory when you want to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

If the outer most dimension is known at the compile time then you can declare the structure with a flexible array member like for example

```
#define N 10
//...
struct myStruct {
      size_t m;
      int a[][N];
};
```

Otherwise instead of the array you should use a pointer of the type `int **`

```
struct myStruct {
      size_t m;
      size_t n;
      int **a;
};
```

where data members `m` and `n` are used to specify dimensions of the allocated dynamically arrays using the pointer `a`.

In both cases arrays are allocated dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

You can allocate it some amount of memory, for example 5 times 5 using malloc and then reallocate in case it's not enough.

E.g.:

```
int *m= (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```